# Powershell - List all folders in a directory, pull latest .bak file in each folder, zip it, copy it to a directory

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that takes the list of folders in a directory and zips the latest .bak file and copies it into another directory.

There are two folders that I do not want it to look in for the .bak files. How do I exclude these folders? I have tried multiple ways of -Exclude statements and I haven't had any luck.

The folders I would like to ignore are "New folder" and "New folder1"

```
$source = "C:\DigiHDBlah"
$filetype = "bak"

$list=Get-ChildItem -Path $source -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
foreach ($element in $list) {
$fn = Get-ChildItem "$source\$element\*" -Include "*.$filetype" | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
$bn=(Get-Item $fn).Basename
$CompressedFile=$bn + ".zip"
$fn| Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$source\$element\$bn.zip"
Copy-Item -path "$source\$element\$CompressedFile" -Destination "C:\DigiHDBlah2"
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use the `Directory` property on the files that you find, and the `-NotLike` operator to do a simple match for the folders you don't want. I would also simplify the search by using a wildcard:

```
$Dest = "C:\DigiHDBlah2"
$files = Get-ChildItem "$source\*\*.$filetype" | Where{$_.Directory -NotLike '*\New Folder' -and $_.Directory -NotLike '*\New Folder1'} | Sort LastWriteTime | Group Directory | ForEach{$_.Group[0]}
ForEach($file in $Files){
    $CompressedFilePath = $File.FullName + ".zip"
    $file | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $CompressedFilePath
    Copy-Item $CompressedFilePath -Dest $Dest
}
```

Or, if you want to just supply a list of folders to exclude you could do a little string manipulation on the directoryName property to just get the last folder, and see if it is in a list of excludes like:

```
$Excludes = @('New Folder','New Folder1')
$Dest = "C:\DigiHDBlah2"
$files = Get-ChildItem "$source\*\*.$filetype" | Where{$_.DirectoryName.Split('\')[-1] -NotIn $Excludes} | Sort LastWriteTime | Group Directory | ForEach{$_.Group[0]}
ForEach($file in $Files){
    $CompressedFilePath = $File.FullName + ".zip"
    $file | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $CompressedFilePath
    Copy-Item $CompressedFilePath -Dest $Dest
}
```